# Facebook Embedded Video Player API

Tags: html, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi guys i am embedding a facebook video and just wanna ask whats wrong with my code because FB.Event.subscribe function wont trigger but the video loads.

```
<html>
<title>My Website</title>
<head>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  console.log("Aw");
  FB.init({
    appId      : '628101554415776',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v3.2'
  });

  // Get Embedded Video Player API Instance
  var my_video_player;
  FB.Event.subscribe('xfbml.ready', function(msg) {
    console.log("Wew");
    if (msg.type === 'video') {
      my_video_player = msg.instance;
      console.log(my_video_player);
    }

  });

  var myEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying', function(e) {
    console.log("Playing");
  });
};
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <script async defer src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/jimcel.longos/videos/3081111611928745/" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably because you are not using XFBML, but put the player there by putting an iframe into your document directly … Pretty sure you need to do it this way, if you want to interact with it via the player API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/#3--place-embedded-video-player-tag

Comment: tried it but still wont work

Comment: can you pls tell me how to use XFBML?

Comment: `<div class="fb-video" …>` _is_ the XFBML version. If this does not work as documented, file a bug report with Facebook.